# How do I eliminate union with undefined in partial index type?

Tags: typescript, union-types, object-object-mapping

I have an `objectMap()` function which takes an object, applies a function to each value, and returns an object with the same keys but different values. I've written the following declaration for it:

```js
declare function objectMap<TInputObject, TOutputValue>(
        target: TInputObject,
        callback: (currentValue: TInputObject[keyof TInputObject]) => TOutputValue,
    ): {[k in keyof TInputObject]: TOutputValue};
```

I expect this to call the callback function with the type found in the object's values, and return an object with the same key-structure as the input object. This works perfectly with most types of object, such as simple maps and even unions of string literals:

```js
type in1 = {[k: string]: string}

type keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
type in2 = {[k in keys]: number}
```

but it breaks down with optional keys of string literal union types:

```js
type keys = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
type in = {[key in keys]?: number }
```

In this case, when I try to use the function:

```js
const obj : {[key in keys]?: number} = {a: 1, b: 2}
const result = objectMap(obj, x => x+1)
```

The variable `x` gets the type `number | undefined` (even though all of the keys that exist have an actual number value), and `result` also winds up having undefineds in addition to the optional keys.

How can I change the declaration of `objectMap()` so that I get the expected results, where `x` is simply `number` and `result` is `{[k in keys]?: number`?

Comment: The types `{a?: number}` and `{a?: number | undefined}` are identical, assuming you have `--strictNullChecks` on.  In TypeScript it is (as of TS3.5) not always possible to [distinguish a missing property from one which is present with an `undefined` value](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195).

Comment: Also, please try to edit this code into a [mcve] which demonstrates the issue you are seeing.  As it stands, `objectMap({a: 1, b: 2}, x => x + 1)` does not have the problem you're describing; `x` is inferred as `number` and the output type is `{a: number; b: number}`.

Comment: @jcalz I have strict null checks turned on, that's part of what causes the problem (though I didn't realize until I turned it off just now that that's what was involved). If I turn it off the type of `x` collapses down to just `number` and everything is fine.

Comment: @jcalz And thanks for catching the problem with the example, I was trying to make a minimal example and accidentally condensed it too much. Edited.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend turning off `--strictNullChecks`; it generally solves more problems than it creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it depends on the implementation of `objectMap()`; let's assume that for each key `k` in `Object.keys(target)`, you first make sure that `target[k]` is not `undefined` (which can happen if `k` is an optional key) before calling `callback` on it.  If so, then you can slightly modify the signature of `objectMap()` so that the `callback` parameter does not need to worry about `undefined` parameters, by using the [predefined conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#predefined-conditional-types) `Exclude<U, X>`... which takes a union type `U` and removes any constituents assignable to `X`, like so:

```
function objectMap<I, O>(
  target: I,
  callback: (currentValue: Exclude<I[keyof I], undefined>) => O
) {
  const ret = {} as { [K in keyof I]: O };
  let k: keyof I;
  for (k in target) {
    const tk = target[k];
    if (typeof tk !== "undefined") {
      ret[k] = callback(tk as Exclude<I[keyof I], undefined>);
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Given that signature, you can now use `objectMap()` like this:

```
interface A {
  a?: number;
  b: number;
  c?: number;
}
const a: A = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const result = objectMap(a, x => x.toFixed());
// const result: {a?: string | undefined, b: string, c?: string | undefined }
console.log(result); // {a: "1", b: "2"}
```

So in this case, the `A` interface has optional numeric properties `"a"` and `"c"`, and a required numeric property `"b"`.  The callback is of type `(x: number)=>string`, and the returned result type has the same optional and required property keys, but the values are `string` types.  (Note that the type `{a?: string | undefined, b: string, c?: string | undefined}` is identical to the type `{a?: string, b: string, c?: string}`) which is about the best the compiler can do if all it knows about the `a` value at compile time is that it is assignable to `A`.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABHARgKwKbQLIEMAOAPAJIA0iA8gHwAUAUIolLgE4DmGUAXImQ4hFwAbISlwQA1jxoQQLFhjBQAasJAYeAUQAeEISAAmGEgG0JGAJ5xgvALrlwR4DDAYDVAJSIAvFUp0vAG9+CAQAZyhEBUjvRECAX0RcMLjEEwBpRBdEcysbYlseCkR4gG5+IU4cnlzrXnLGYDgWRBoJLKRmdk4g-kZQsAimdtiujigzWwbGLJsaKAt8DDqodoBCb1iAIkcMZ1cDLd6ZmejJnwFhUXEJefbkxB09Q2NiM0s6gocwJxc3T2mjHi-GBjGiciQ0XKwLoLigGBYwHEGEQAEE4vxcAB+HhgEAAWxQCOmKFxBKJLGmEBxiDxhOJdGBAyGuB46NigSSPAAjORSYgAEwlcrMyIKMIgIQxZDoLBQPD4Gi4cjaHx+bQAOigcAAYjBtG4aB4POUAPSmgThMUYCVSniBbE8CIsFxsRAAH0Qu32bj5TqgLrAbHI1P9gbdnu9fwMJTozLglQ1QjgbBo4slUBNiHNcVZiC23K2fvzAq28SAA)

Comment: The implementation is https://github.com/xixixao/object-map/blob/master/index.js (I'm trying to write types for the existing library). It does not check for `undefined`, but I was expecting the case where the value was present but undefined to be handled by the type system. It looks like [#13195](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195) describes exactly the problem I'm having and there's no way to precisely type this right now. In the interim I'll write my own function that uses `Exclude` to handle this. Thanks for your help!